# UIPickerView in cell like 'DateCell'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I have downloaded the sample code for the [DateCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/DateCell/Listings/MyTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866-MyTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6). Now I want to do the same with a PickerView, above the UIDatePicker, in another Section. How can I do that? I've tried it before by modifying the code, but without success. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: What part are you having issues with?

Comment: @bobnoble For example I don't know how I has to change the method `hasPickerForIndexPath:`

Comment: Assuming all else is the same, you only need to change `UIDatePicker *checkDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];` to `UIPickerView *checkDatePicker = (UIPickerView *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];`. It is advisable to also change all identifiers that include "DatePicker", e.g., `kDatePickerTag`, to a more appropriate name such as `kMyPickerViewTag`, and `checkDatePickerCell` to `checkMyPickerCell`.